# Why I cannot create a folder inside wherever I want

Tags: permissions, root

I am the administrator of my computer. I have created my first account as ilhan. However when I go to /var/www/ it says that the owner is root etc. And I cannot create a user there. **What should I do to be a full administrator in my PC?**

Whatever folder I go I'm like third degree citizen in my Ubuntu. Like it is someone else's computer.

Comment: Do you have Root privilege???

Comment: @smn_onrocks, only when on terminal when I do `sudo su`.

Comment: Do you have Apache HTTP Server (apache2) installed on your computer?

Comment: @karel, yes, I have installed Apache.

Comment: I also installed Webmin. It creates new users for every virtual server. I want to move the folders under my control.

Comment: @karel, this question is not related with Apache. It is abot being or not being the administrator of my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

By default only root can edit /var/www/

Use

```
    sudo chmod 771 /var/www/
```

To change the permission to allow group users to write to it.

Comment: But it is a temporary solution. I don't want every time everywhere to sudo su. Should I install server version of Ubuntu or an another distro?

Comment: Yes. That is part of the security of Linux. If you had full access by default then you could very easily cause lots of damage to your system.

Comment: I don't have this kind of limitations in Ubuntu at atlantic.net.